# A problem dealing with a two-way set-associative cache

Tags: computer-architecture, cache

This is Problem 13-4 from the book "Logic and Computer Design Fundamentals" by M. Morris Mano and Charles R. Kime. I did the problem. I would like somebody to confirm that my answer is correct or tell me that my answer is wrong.
Problem:
A two-way set-associative cache in a system with 24-bit addresses has four 4-byte words per line and a capacity of 1 MB. Addressing
is to the byte level.
(a) How many bits are there in the index and the tag?
(b) Indicate the value of the index in hexadecimal for cache entries from the following main memory address in hexadecimal:
     F8C00F, 14AC89, 48CF0FF and 3ACF05
(c) Can all the cache entries from part(b) be in the cache simultaneously?
Answer: (a)
Each line (or block) in the cache is 16 bytes. This means that we have 1024*1024 / 16 = 65536 blocks in the cache. That means
that there are 65536/2 = 32768 rows in the cache. A row is identified by 15 bits. So the index is 15 bits. You
need 4 bits to identify which byte in a block. Therefore, the tag bits are 32 - 15 - 4 = 13 bits.
(b)
To find the value of the index, we take the address and ignore the last 4 bits. We then take the next 5 bits. So for
F8C00F, the index is 0. For 14AC89 the index is 08 (in 5 bits). For 48CF0FF the index is 0F(in 5 bits). For 3ACF05 the index is 10.
(c)
Since they all go in different rows, all four entries will fit.

Here is an updated answer to part b.
(b)
To find the value of the index, we take the address and ignore the last 4 bits. We then take the next 15 bits. So for
F8C00F, the index is 0C00(in 15 bits). For 14AC89 the index is 4ACA (in 15 bits). For 48CF0FF the index is 4F0F(in 15 bits). For
3ACF05 the index is 2CF0 (in 15 bits).

Do I have the answer right now?

Correction:
For 14AC89 the index is 4AC8 (in 15 bits)

Comment: -1 For posting homework solutions and encouraging cheating. There's no reason to have this posted.

Comment: @brhans How can you say there is no attempt? I posted a solution.

Comment: @KingDuken I am not currently taking any classes. I am trying to learn this material.

Comment: In part (a), you calculate that the index is 15 bits. So why are you giving 5-bit answers in part (b)?

Comment: @DaveTweed You are right. my answer in part b is wrong. I will update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those are the correct numbers for part (b).

Comment: I updated my answer for part b. Do have the entire question right now?